# Drupal 6 administration menu like the one on Drupal 7

Tags: 6, routes

I build a lot of sites, mostly on Drupal 7, so when I have to use Drupal 6 I am totally lost on the admin options, (even using the administrative menu bar).

Since I can't find any module for this issue, I am wondering if I should give it a try to build a module myself to rename and rearrange the admin menu items, but I am not sure, if this is even possible or if that will cause any path issues in modules later.

Comment: If you should give a try building a module depends from your skills on building a module. Creating a module is always extra work, and you [commented](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27621/d6-admin-menu-like-d7#comment26783_27628) saying you want to avoid that. This probably rules out creating a module. For the first point, this question is subjective: The answer is "it depends from your skills on writing a module," and nobody but you knows your skills in writing a module.

Answer (score 0):

Why not building your own menu with the most used functions and show it only for you? I do this all the time for D6 and D7.

Comment: Well as I mentioned I build a lot of sites, that means I am user 1 for all of them, and also I want to save time, not creating extra work... I also want the clients to have some of the admin links, but like D7